# Not getting any console log after submit form in angular 9

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular9

I am not able to get console log data after form submit.. What i have missing here in my below code..
This code is to long sorry for this..

**Html:**

```
   <form [formGroup]="collFormEvening" autocomplete="off" (submit)="onSubmit()">
     <label class="label">Evening [Machine 1]</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text">Cash <small
                    class="mandatory">*</small></span>
        </div>
        <input type="number" formControlName="Cash" class="form-control" required>
        <input type="number" formControlName="Cash2" class="form-control" readonly>
    </div><br>
    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text">Card</span>
        </div>
        <input type="number" formControlName="Card" class="form-control" >
        <input type="" formControlName="Card2" class="form-control" id="dcard"
            readonly>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text">Phone Pay</span>
        </div>
        <input type="number" formControlName="PhonePay" class="form-control"
            id="phonePay">
        <input type="" formControlName="PhonePay2" class="form-control"
            id="dphonePay" readonly>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text">Ecommerce</span>
        </div>
        <input type="number" formControlName="Ecom" class="form-control" >
        <input type="" formControlName="Ecom2" class="form-control"
            readonly>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text">Others</span>
        </div>
        <input type="number" formControlName="Other" class="form-control" >
        <input type="" formControlName="Other2" class="form-control"
            readonly>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text" >1000X</span>
        </div>
        <input type="number" formControlName="Thousand" 
            class="form-control">
        <input type="number" formControlName="Thousand2" 
            class="form-control" readonly>
    </div><br>
    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text" >500X</span>
        </div>
        <input type="number" formControlName="FiveHundred" 
            class="form-control">
        <input type="number" formControlName="FiveHundred2"  readonly
            class="form-control">
    </div><br>
    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text" >100X</span>
        </div>
        <input type="number" formControlName="Hundred" 
            class="form-control">
        <input type="number" formControlName="Hundred2"  readonly
            class="form-control">
    </div><br>
    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text" >50X</span>
        </div>
        <input type="number" formControlName="Fifty"  class="form-control">
        <input type="number" formControlName="Fifty2"  readonly
            class="form-control">
    </div><br>
    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text" >20X</span>
        </div>
        <input type="number" formControlName="Twenty" 
            class="form-control">
        <input type="number" formControlName="Twenty2"  readonly
            class="form-control">
    </div><br>
    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text" >10X</span>
        </div>
        <input type="number" formControlName="Ten" class="form-control">
        <input type="number" formControlName="Ten2"  readonly
            class="form-control">
    </div><br>
    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text" >5X</span>
        </div>
        <input type="number" formControlName="Five"  class="form-control">
        <input type="number" formControlName="Five2"  readonly
            class="form-control">
    </div><br>
    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text" >2X</span>
        </div>
        <input type="number" formControlName="Two" class="form-control">
        <input type="number" formControlName="Two2" readonly
            class="form-control">
    </div><br>
    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text" >1X</span>
        </div>
        <input type="number" formControlName="One" class="form-control">
        <input type="number" formControlName="One2" readonly
            class="form-control">
    </div><br>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" value="Total" class="form-control" readonly>
        <input type="number" formControlName="Total2" 
            class="form-control text-center" readonly>
    </div><br>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4"><br>
            <div type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-1"><i class="fas fa-save mr-2"> 
        </i>Submit</div>
            <button type="reset" value="reset"
                class="btn btn-light mt-2">Clear</button>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**ts:** *This is the ts file and after submit form i am not able to get console data. Is there is any mistake that i have done??*

```
ngOnInit(): void {
this.onKeyUpMethod();
this.onKeyUpMethodEvening();
 }

onSubmit() {
console.log(this.collFormMorning.value);  <--!  here is the code to get form data in console -->
this.collectionService.postItems(this.collFormMorning.value).subscribe(
  (res: any) => {
    this.toastr.success("Sales collection saved successfully !!");
    console.log(res);
    console.log(this.collFormMorning.value);  <--!  here is the code to get form data in console -->

    this.collFormMorning.reset();

  },
  err => {
    if (err.status == 400)
      this.toastr.error('Error !!', 'Authentication failed.');
    else
      this.toastr.error('Network error', 'Authentication failed.');
    console.log(err);
   }
  );

 }
 onKeyUpMethod() {
  this.collFormMorning = this.fb.group({
  Cash: [''],
  Cash2: [''],
  Card: [''],
  Card2: [''],
  PhonePay: [''],
  PhonePay2: [''],
  Ecom: [''],
  Ecom2: [''],
  Other: [''],
  Other2: [''],
  Thousand: [''],
  Thousand2: [''],
  FiveHundred: [''],
  FiveHundred2: [''],
  Hundred: [''],
  Hundred2: [''],
  Fifty: [''],
  Fifty2: [''],
  Twenty: [''],
  Twenty2: [''],
  Ten: [''],
  Ten2: [''],
  Five: [''],
  Five2: [''],
  Two: [''],
  Two2: [''],
  One: [''],
  One2: [''],
  Total: [''],
  Total2: [0],
});

this.collFormMorning.get('Cash').valueChanges
  .subscribe(a => {
    this.collFormMorning.get('Cash2').setValue(a);
    this.setTotalValue();
  })

this.collFormMorning.get('Card').valueChanges
  .subscribe(x => {
    this.collFormMorning.get('Card2').setValue(x);
    this.setTotalValue();
  })

this.collFormMorning.get('PhonePay').valueChanges
  .subscribe(a => {
    this.collFormMorning.get('PhonePay2').setValue(a);
    this.setTotalValue();
  })

this.collFormMorning.get('Ecom').valueChanges
  .subscribe(x => {
    this.collFormMorning.get('Ecom2').setValue(x);
    this.setTotalValue();
  })

this.collFormMorning.get('Other').valueChanges
  .subscribe(x => {
    this.collFormMorning.get('Other2').setValue(x);
    this.setTotalValue();
  })

this.collFormMorning.get('Thousand').valueChanges
  .subscribe(a => {
    this.collFormMorning.get('Thousand2').setValue(a * 1000);
    this.setTotalValue();
  })

this.collFormMorning.get('FiveHundred').valueChanges
  .subscribe(a => {
    this.collFormMorning.get('FiveHundred2').setValue(a * 500);
    this.setTotalValue();
  })

this.collFormMorning.get('Hundred').valueChanges
  .subscribe(x => {
    this.collFormMorning.get('Hundred2').setValue(x * 100);
    this.setTotalValue();
  })

this.collFormMorning.get('Fifty').valueChanges
  .subscribe(a => {
    this.collFormMorning.get('Fifty2').setValue(a * 50);
    this.setTotalValue();
  })

this.collFormMorning.get('Twenty').valueChanges
  .subscribe(x => {
    this.collFormMorning.get('Twenty2').setValue(x * 20);
    this.setTotalValue();
  })

this.collFormMorning.get('Ten').valueChanges
  .subscribe(a => {
    this.collFormMorning.get('Ten2').setValue(a * 10);
    this.setTotalValue();
  })

this.collFormMorning.get('Five').valueChanges
  .subscribe(x => {
    this.collFormMorning.get('Five2').setValue(x * 5);
    this.setTotalValue();
  })

this.collFormMorning.get('Two').valueChanges
  .subscribe(a => {
    this.collFormMorning.get('Two2').setValue(a * 2);
    this.setTotalValue();
  })

this.collFormMorning.get('One').valueChanges
  .subscribe(x => {
    this.collFormMorning.get('One2').setValue(x * 1);
    this.setTotalValue();
  })
}

setTotalValue() {
 const data = this.collFormMorning.value;
 let sum = 0;
 Object.keys(data).map(key => {
   if (['Cash2', 'Card2', 'PhonePay2', 'Ecom2', 'Other2', 'Thousand2', 'FiveHundred2', 'Hundred2', 
     'Fifty2', 'Twenty2', 'Ten2', 'Five2', 'Two2', 'One2'].indexOf(key) !== -1 && data[key]) {
    sum += data[key];
    //console.log(sum);
   }
  });
 this.collFormMorning.get('Total2').setValue(sum);
};
```

**Is there any missing in this code.. please help me to resolve this problem** **I am beginner in angular**

When i post form data, i am getting this error.. when i change type="number" to text it works fine.
Picture of error.. please take a look.

[SS of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54VHa.png)

**Controller:**

```
    // POST: api/CollectionEntry
    // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties 
       you want to bind to, for
    // more details, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2123754.
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<SalesCollectionEntry>> 
     PostSalesCollectionEntry(SalesCollectionEntry salesCollectionEntry)
    {
        _context.SalesEntry.Add(salesCollectionEntry);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return CreatedAtAction("GetSalesCollectionEntry", new { id = 
       salesCollectionEntry.Id }, salesCollectionEntry);
    }
```

**Class:**

```
   public class SalesCollectionEntry
   {
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Division { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Terninal { get; set; }
    public string Shift { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime PostDateTime { get; set; }
    public decimal Cash { get; set; }
    public decimal Cash2 { get; set; }
    .
    .
    . //etc
 }
```

**Updated Code,**
**Service class:**

```
export class CollectionService {

//collectionInfo : Collection[]= [];

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

readonly BaseURL = 'https://localhost:44372/api';

// save data of Items to db 
postItems(data){
return this.http.post(this.BaseURL + "/CollectionEntry", data);
 }
}
```

Comment: May be you see already reset form values. If you can, add please link to StackBlitz.

Comment: Now its working fine after changing div tag to button.. I have just done mistake here .. Thank you V.Tur your are always there for me to help.. lots of love .. :-)

Comment: V.Tur i am getting error while posting form data to server.. i have attatched SS pic in above.. please take a look.. Do u have any idea about this.. I am stucked here..

Comment: For answer not enough information :( Need to see what JSON you send, and I not strong in C#, but may be on backend you need to get stream and then serialize it?

Comment: i am sending form data (ie.number) which is denomination form.. you have done the denomination form (calculation code). When i post other form it works fine.

Comment: I have posted all the required code above.

Answer (score 1):

```
<form [formGroup]="collFormEvening" autocomplete="off" (submit)="onSubmit()">
```

in this html page , I guess the [formGroup] not equal the console.log parameter

```
console.log(this.collFormMorning.value);
```